# Map array of strings to an array of integers

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have a column in a data frame as colors say `c("Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Orange")`.
I would like to get it as `c(1,2,2,3)`.

```
Red as 1
Blue as 2
Orange as 3
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this other than the obvious if/else or switch functions?

Comment: See `match(x, unique(x))` or, on a more formal note, `as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set up a named vector, describing the link between colour and integers (i.e. specifically how the strings map to the integers):

```
colors=c(1,2,3)
names(colors)=c("Red", "Blue", "Orange")
```

Now use the named vector to generate a list of numbers associated with the colours in your data frame:

```
>colors[c("Red","Blue","Blue","Orange")]
   Red   Blue   Blue Orange 
     1      2      2      3
```

UPDATE to address questions below.  Here's an example of what I think you're trying to do.

```
dataframe=data.frame(Gender=c("F","F","M","F","F","M"))
strings=sort(unique(dataframe$Gender))
colors=1:length(strings)
names(colors)=strings
dataframe$Colours=colors[dataframe$Gender]
```

Can have a look at the result:

```
> dataframe
  Gender Colours
1      F      1
2      F      1
3      M      2
4      F      1
5      F      1
6      M      2
```

Note that this example assumes that you have no specific mapping between Gender and Colours in mind.  If this is really the case, then it might be simpler to just follow the comment from @alexis_laz instead.

Comment: The thing is the number of rows in my data frame runs in the thousands

Comment: @user2500781.  You could modify `CnrL` solution to setNames(1:3,unique(dat$colors))[dat$colors]
   Red   Blue   Blue Orange 
     1      2      2      3

Comment: I don't see why this is a problem: thousands=sample(c("Red", "Blue", "Orange"),2000,replace=TRUE); colors[thousands]

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify the question.  Do you have thousands of unique strings or thousands of rows in your column of strings that you need to map to integers, or both?

Comment: I'll try this out it sounds promising. And I have about a hundred unique strings in the column.

Comment: This might help: 
strings=sort(unique(dataframe$cols)); 
colors=1:length(strings); 
names(colors)=strings

Comment: Hey. I like this approach but it just doesn't seem to work. Suppose my column has two unique values of gender - 'M' and 'F'. I need to change them to 1 and 2. strings=sort(unique(dataframe$Gender)); colors=1:length(strings); names(colors)=strings does not do the trick. The characters are not being replaced by the integers.

Comment: Brilliant. Made my code considerably faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I must be missing something, but this method would work I believe.  Having coerced your column with words (below, "names") to a factor, you `revalue` them by your numbers in "colors".

```
require(plyr)

colors <- c("1","2","3")
names <- c("Red", "Blue", "Orange")
df <- data.frame(names, colors)
df$names <- as.factor(df$names)
df$names <- revalue(x = df$names, c("Red" = 1, "Blue" = 2, "Orange" = 3))
```

Comment: "Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 
  no methods for ‘revalue’ and no documentation for it as a function"

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I added require(plyr)

Comment: If you like it, you can give it a plus, with the up arrow over the 0.

Comment: Thanks. The official doc is not clear about whether it mutates the frame or returns a new column and your example resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using *car::recode()* function:

```
library(car)

recode(x, "'Red'=1; 'Blue'=2; 'Orange'=3;")
# [1] 1 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function based on previous code:

```
# Recode 'string' into 'integer'
recode_str_int <- function(df, feature) {

  # 1. Unique values

  # 1.1. 'string' values
  list_str <- sort(unique(df[, feature]))

  # 1.2. 'integer' values
  list_int <- 1:length(list_str)

  # 2. Create new feature

  # 2.1. Names
  names(list_int) = list_str
  df$feature_new = list_int[df[, feature]]

  # 3. Result
  df$feature_new

} # recode_str_int
```

Call it like:

```
 df$new_feature <- recode_str_int(df, "feature")
```