# Empty numeric value in a numeric vector in R

Tags: r, vector, numeric, radix

I want to create a numeric vector in R with a placeholder. Just like in a chracter vector like:

```
characterVec <- c("a", "b", "", "d")
```

This gives me a `characterVec` vector with a length of 4.

How can I create a numeric vector with a length of 4, but still has one empty value? For example, I would like to know what do I put into the question mark in the following vector.

```
numericVec <- c(1, 2, ?, 4)
```

Comment: `numericVec <- c(1, 2, NA, 4)` ?

Comment: `numeric` creates numeric vector of given length (`numeric(4)`). However, I don't understand what you mean by *empty numeric value*. Is it `0`, `NA`?

Comment: This answer might be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849859/8675075

Comment: Thanks @RLave that will also work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you can use a named vector to create a data dictionary linking letters to corresponding numbers:

```
# data dictionary
dat <- 1:26
names(dat) <- letters
```

then map dictionary onto your vector

```
characterVec <- c("a", "b", "", "d")
numVec <- dat[characterVec]
```

gives

```
   a    b <NA>    d 
   1    2   NA    4
```

You can remove the vector names with `unname()`:

```
numVec <- unname(dat[characterVec])
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul and, that will be a solution that gets the job done in my case :)